# Silverlight: Controls looking different in Visual Studio v. debugging

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a text box that appears in a certain size and position in the Visual Studio Silverlight preview window. When I actually run the app, it appears to be much wider, and lower on the page. Why is this? (Sometimes I can fix the problem by deleting the control and making a new one like it, but it's frustrating.)

This is the XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Cost, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Name="CostTextBox" Margin="269,410,458,174" Height="23" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want real WYSIWYG you are better off with Expression Blend.

The visual editor in VS 2010 is meant to be an improvement on Xaml editing (which it is), but it is not a designer tool.

Sorry, I know blend is not cheap but it is well worth the money for any professional Silverlight developer.

Comment: I actually do have Blend. Is it possible to import an existing VS project into Blend and edit it there?

Comment: If you right click on a Xaml file in the project explorer in visual studio you should have a "open in Expression Blend" option. The 2 products are designed to work in sync.